# Can't connect with DNS Seedlist Connection Format but works fine with standard connection string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am trying to connect to my atlas cluster but it gives me time out error. I tried connecting to local mongodb, it works and using standard connection string for the same cluster:

```
(mongo "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-n1kmr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-n1kmr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-n1kmr.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin  --username <username> --password <password>)
```

works too!

However, when I try to connect with  DNS Seedlist Connection Format, it gives me a timeout error when I run

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-n1kmr.mongodb.net/test"  --username <username>
```

Error message:
**DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up service "":This operation returned because the timeout period expired.**
[cmd line image with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgh6s.png)

My mongo shell version is **v4.2.6**

```
>>mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v4.2.6
git version: 20364840b8f1af16917e4c23c1b5f5efd8b352f8
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: 2012plus
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

and db version **v4.2.6**

```
>> mongod --version
db version v4.2.6
git version: 20364840b8f1af16917e4c23c1b5f5efd8b352f8
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: 2012plus
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No. I just used standard connection string.